# linux curl POST request not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget, curl, http

I am trying to make a POST request using curl to retrieve exam results from the page : [result odd](http://wbutech.net/result_odd.php) .... I am using the following syntax but various errors are showing up (like content has moved permanently) although I am using the `-L` option... `curl -L --data-urlencode semno=7&rectype=1&rollno=10400111005 http://wbutech.net/show-result.php`

can anyone please post the working syntax here which works on the above said link correctly and retrieves the results?

(Sample Usage is enter roll as 10400111005 and click semester7 button under regular students...that is what I am trying to do using the above curl syntax)

Answer (score 1):

[Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) - the literal `&` signs are interpreted as command separators.

Answer (score 1):

Use quotation mark for your post data, like this

```
curl -L --data-urlencode "semno=7&rectype=1&rollno=10400111005" http://wbutech.net/show-result.php
```

Also you should not use --data-urlencode for this situation, use -d parameter.

Sample output (-d parameter):

```
$ curl -d "post1=ddş5%%%%iiüğ&post2=dfdfişğ**?" http://reddoc.net/curl.php
GET:Array
(
)                                                                                                                                                                                               
POST:Array                                                                                                                                                                                      
(                                                                                                                                                                                               
    [post1] => ddş5%%%%iiüğ                                                                                                                                                                     
    [post2] => dfdfişğ**?                                                                                                                                                                       
)
```

Sample output (--data-urlencode parameter):

```
curl --data-urlencode "post1=ddş5%%%%iiüğ&post2=dfdfişğ**?" http://reddoc.net/curl.php
GET:Array
(
)
POST:Array
(
    [post1] => ddş5%%%%iiüğ&post2=dfdfişğ**?
)
```